# Amendment 01 Telegram bot button drive menu via Google Sheets Apps Script

Tags: javascript, telegram, telegram-bot

have amended Google Web App based on JavaScript source code as per 20200403
sadly, still does not work

problem: buttons do not show up on Telegram group, related to the group chat_id, when I type:
menu

JavaScript should construct and send back to Telegram group:
InlineKeyboardMarkup object (This object represents an inline keyboard that appears right next to the message it belongs to.)

Google Web App JavaScript source code follows:

```
var vApiTokenTelegram = "????????????????????????"; // @MediaFlamengoBot API token
var vUrlTelegram = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + vApiTokenTelegram;
var vWebAppUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/?????????????????????/exec";

function sendReplyMarkupMessage( chat_id, text, oInlineKeyboard ) {
    var encodedText = encodeURIComponent(text);

    GmailApp.sendEmail(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail(), "Telegram Bot Update", JSON.stringify(oInlineKeyboard, null, 4));    

    var req = new Request(vUrlTelegram +    "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + chat_id + "&text=" + text + "&reply_markup=" + oInlineKeyboard );
    fetch(req)
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(blob => {
        console.log('Response: ', blob)
    });
    //Logger.log(response.getContentText());  
}

function menu( chat_id ) {
    var oInlineKeyboard = JSON.stringify({
        inline_keyboard: [
            [{ text: 'Some button text 1', callback_data: '1' }],
            [{ text: 'Some button text 2', callback_data: '2' }],
            [{ text: 'Some button text 3', callback_data: '3' }],
            [{ text: 'Some button text 4', callback_data: '4' }],            
            [{ text: 'Some button text 5', callback_data: '5' }]
        ]
    });
    sendReplyMarkupMessage( chat_id, "test", oInlineKeyboard );
}
```

gmail logs the following, no JSON object:
"{\"inline_keyboard\":[[{\"text\":\"Some button text 1\",\"callback_data\":\"1\"}],[{\"text\":\"Some button text 2\",\"callback_data\":\"2\"}],[{\"text\":\"Some button text 3\",\"callback_data\":\"3\"}],[{\"text\":\"Some button text 4\",\"callback_data\":\"4\"}],[{\"text\":\"Some button text 5\",\"callback_data\":\"5\"}]]}"

thanks in advance for any help

Trajano

Comment: have implemented the following, but sadly it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining the `reply_markup` twice. Your using this `"&reply_markup=" + reply_markup` in the 'send' function. But the `reply_markup` is also defined in the options;

```
function menu( chat_id ) {
    var options = {
        reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
            inline_keyboard: [
            ...
```

Try removing the `reply_markup` and set the options as an array;

```
function sendReplyMarkupMessage( chat_id, text, reply_markup ) {
    var encodedText = encodeURIComponent(text);
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(vUrlTelegram +    "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + chat_id + "&text=" + text + "&reply_markup=" + reply_markup );
    Logger.log(response.getContentText());  
}

function menu( chat_id ) {
    var options = JSON.stringify({
        inline_keyboard: [
            [{ text: 'Some button text 1', callback_data: '1' }],
            [{ text: 'Some button text 2', callback_data: '2' }],
            [{ text: 'Some button text 3', callback_data: '3' }]
        }
    ]);
    sendReplyMarkupMessage( chat_id, "test", options );
}
```

---

**Edit**;
I believe [`UrlFetchApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) is a google script function.

**Edit 2**; You're right, the array in `JSON.stringify` should be an object!

I've created a JSFiddle bases on your code; [Take a look at it here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lo3es5na/5/).

Output

<sup>After placing your own bot token + chat_id</sup>

[image]

---

Based on Google App Script, you should use something like this (Tested succesfully);

```
function myFunction() {
    let token = '123456788:AAdadadadbMTcMvY10SZGsbIJ2rdFXJiXmbFw';
    let url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token + "/sendMessage";

    var options = {
        'method' : 'post',
        'contentType': 'application/json',
        'payload' : JSON.stringify({
            'chat_id': 11111111,
            'text': 'fsdfdsfsdf',
            'reply_markup': {
                inline_keyboard: [
                    [{ text: 'Some button text 1', callback_data: '1' }],
                    [{ text: 'Some button text 2', callback_data: '2' }],
                    [{ text: 'Some button text 3', callback_data: '3' }]
                ]
            }
        })
    };
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);  
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    Logger.log(res);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help
have amended the quote but still does not work

any idea?
thanks

Comment: @TrajanoRoberto Did you edit the original question based on my answer? There are still 2 times `reply_markup` in the JSON, remove the one in the `options`

Comment: yes

note: code amended upon suggestion; sadly, still does not work

regards

Comment: Please try my `menu` function, there are still 2 `reply_markup` keys in your request.

Comment: thanks for the reply, however I’ve modified the source code and no longer use 2 x reply_markup; the original post with the dubious source code has been deleted; please refer to the modified JavaScript source code:
Appreciate your time and effort in assisting us; cheers TrajanoRoberto

Comment: @TrajanoRoberto I just saw the edit. You've changed the name of the variable, not the real content. At the end of the url you have `"&reply_markup=" + oInlineKeyboard` but the `oInlineKeyboard` variable already contains a `reply_markup` as shown in the `menu` function: `var oInlineKeyboard = {
        reply_markup:` You should copy mine, I've removed it there ;)

Comment: have edited as suggested, but it does not work
error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token : (line 282, file "Code.gs")

function menu( chat_id ) {

    var options = JSON.stringify([

        inline_keyboard: [

            [{ text: 'Some button text 1', callback_data: '1' }],

            [{ text: 'Some button text 2', callback_data: '2' }],

            [{ text: 'Some button text 3', callback_data: '3' }]

        ]

    ]);

    sendReplyMarkupMessage( chat_id, "test", options );

}

Comment: @TrajanoRoberto Yep, your right, there should be an object (`{}`) in the JSON stringify. Please see my edit. I've also made a JSFiddle so you can see it working ;) Hope it helps!

Comment: 0stone0; edited the code; still no buttons show up on Telegram group SmartPhone screen; I must be missing something? tried to run your code on fiddle, entering the chat_id, but still no buttons show up? have used gmail to log oInlineKeyboard, no JSON object??

"{\"inline_keyboard\":[[{\"text\":\"Some button text 1\",\"callback_data\":\"1\"}],[{\"text\":\"Some button text 2\",\"callback_data\":\"2\"}],[{\"text\":\"Some button text 3\",\"callback_data\":\"3\"}],[{\"text\":\"Some button text 4\",\"callback_data\":\"4\"}],[{\"text\":\"Some button text 5\",\"callback_data\":\"5\"}]]}"

Comment: 0stone0; I can add you to the telegram group (please provide your username) and give you access to the google web app; I am going insane with this simple piece of code; I've got everything else working; acquaint requested buttons, hence trying to get InlineKeyboardMarkup working; please help; thanks

Comment: 0stone0: please send Telegram message to @TrajanoRoberto with your gmail eMail address to share the Google Web App and to add you to the Telegram group; thanks mate